# Unable to delete controls inside toolstripcontainer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, designer

I met strange issue during designing winform. I placed a few controls inside toolstripcontainer and now I cannot delete them. It's also impossible to delete whole Toolstripcontainer.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 plus some extra patches.
Is it a bug in Visual Studio? Is there any workaround? Or I'm lacking of knowledge of VS?
Best regards,
Tomo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try closing the designer, clean your solution and reopen the designer window?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go in the .Designer.Cs and delete line manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have visual Studio 2014, but I think it will help.

Usually you cant delete "toolStripContainer" when you set "Dock" property value of "toolStripContainer" = "Fill".

In this situation:

1. You have to Click right button of the mouse at the "toolStripContainer" to get context menu.
2. At the context menu you will have to select -> "Document Structure".
3. After this, at the right tool-bar, you will get tool bar "Document Structure". Select there root element of "toolStripContainer" that you need to delete from your form.
4. Click on it by the right button of the mouse. At the context menu select "Delete". Or select it and just change value of the "Dock" property of the "toolStripContainer", after this you will be able to move this control  at form designer again.